# When to construct sentence without Is and Was?

Tags: sentence-construction, active-vs-passive

> "Those,who killed in the accident, were residents of our area"

Is above sentence construction is correct? is it in Active voice? Is World killed is as adjective?

If I Construct below sentence can it be correct? Is it in Passive voice ?

> a) "Those who were killed in the accident were residents of our area"
>
> b) "Man who are killed in Georgia sentenced for decade-old Delaware murder."

I found these kind of constructions in news paper:

> Three members of tourist family killed in accident

<sup>([thenews.com.pk](https://www.thenews.com.pk/archive/print/517105-three-members-of-tourist-family-killed-in-accident))</sup>

Comment: Of the three sentences, only the one marked a) is correct.  The others are not grammatical.  Could you please add more detail explaining why this grammar is confusing to you?  That would help us write a better answer.

Comment: I found these kind of construction s in news paper

Comment: @Andrew: Example #1 isn't actually "incorrect" - it's just "unlikely". Consider *Those who killed (the enemy) in WW2 were not murderers, they were simply soldiers following orders.*

Comment: https://www.thenews.com.pk/archive/print/517105-three-members-of-tourist-family-killed-in-accident

Comment: Above link for sample where you will find the construction using "those who killed in the"

Comment: Headlines often lack essential words:  "Three members of [a] tourist family [were] killed in [an] accident."  You can consider [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) to use a grammar that's quite different from plain English.

Comment: May be some comas in my original sentence will help

Comment: But b is not valid even in headlinese. "Man who was killed..." or "Men who were killed..." would be gramatically valid but nonsensical (how can a dead man be sentenced?), whereas "Man who killed..." is possible but clumsy.

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to derive (and roll his own) plain English usage from headlinese examples, Daniel.  Since headlinese isn't plain English, these valiant attempts happen also to be failures.  And, no, commas don't help, user4084.  Here, they seem merely to mark the subordinate clause as parenthetical and non-restrictive.  They don't turn the active clause into a passive modifier.

Answer (score 1):

> "Those,who killed in the accident, were residents of our area"

Q. Is above sentence construction is correct?

A. No. It should be either:

> Those who *were* killed in the accident were residents of our area.
>   **or**
>   Those killed in the accident were residents of our area.

I believe these would be examples of *passive voice*, as *active voice* is characterised by the subject carrying out the verb. That is not present in this sentence.

You also asked about newspaper headlines and gave this example:

> "Three members of tourist family killed in accident"

Newspaper headlines often omit words for sake of space and are not the best examples for someone learning English as a second language. News headlines have a set of rules all of their own. The example you give is typical and makes sense to me, but if it were written grammatically it would likely say:

> Three members of **a** tourist family **have been** killed in **an** accident.

If you read the article beneath the headline you will find that it almost certainly expands on the headline in a proper grammatical way.

Comment: "Those killed in the accident were residents of our area." Is passive voice or active voice?

Comment: @user4084 I believe these would be examples of *passive voice*, as *active voice* is characterised by the subject carrying out the verb. That is not present in this sentence.

Comment: Thanks, to conclude, omission or inclusion of *Is and was* does not make any difference in actual meaning.

Comment: Is *Killed* is used as an adjective?

Comment: Regarding "Those killed in the accident were residents of our area", the only finite clause is copular and voiceless.  The "were" is a form of the verb *to be*, which does not have any transitivity.  However, the participle "killed" is a form of the transitive verb *to kill*.  It does have a voice, and the so-called past participle exhibits a **passive voice**.  "Killed" isn't technically an adjective, but it does take an adjectival role here, forming a phrase that directly modifies the demonstrative pronoun "those".  So, not quite used **as** and adjective, but used **like** an adjective.